# Fl_X compile error

Tags: c++, x11, fltk

I have been modifying a project and now when I try to compile the software I get the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:32:0:
main.h: In member function ‘virtual void Fl_Root::show()’:
main.h:41:17: error: incomplete type ‘Fl_X’ used in nested name specifier
   if (!shown()) Fl_X::set_xid(this, RootWindow(fl_display, fl_screen));
                 ^
```

The menu.h file is very simple and contains just the following:

```
extern void ShowMenu();

class Fl_Root : public Fl_Window {
    int handle(int);
public:
    Fl_Root() : Fl_Window(0,0,Fl::w(),Fl::h()) { 
    }
    void show() {
        if (!shown()) Fl_X::set_xid(this, RootWindow(fl_display, fl_screen));
    }
    void flush() {
    }
};
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know the definition for `F1_X`.

Comment: Thanks Drew, any thoughts on how to make it aware of Fl_X?

Comment: I don't have access to this code, so I can't tell you where that definition exists.  If it's in a header, include that header.

Comment: Fl_X is a platform dependent file.  It lives in the platform specific code like win32.H or x.H.  It should automatically be included when you include Fl.H.  How did you install FLTK?

Comment: I have tried adding an "#include <FL/x.H>" to the top of the file, but it didn't make any difference.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Everything is installed correctly as this compiled without issues earlier today before I started making changes to the codebase.  It has to be something like a missing header file or a declaration somewhere, I just don't know what.

Comment: I also added "#include <FL/Fl.H>" to the top of the file and it still bombs...

Comment: Doing a quick 'find' and 'grep -H' shows that the 'Fl_X' class is actually in the 'Fl_Window.H' file, however adding an '#include' for that file does not resolve the problem either.

Comment: I found the problem!  I commented out a "#define FL_INTERNALS 1" call before the "#include" statements - oops!  Just wanted to post in case this helps someone else.

Comment: @user1646428 That is generous of you to share the answer you discovered.  You should post that solution as an **answer** (instead of a comment) and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Drew's suggestion!

I found the problem! I commented out a "#define FL_INTERNALS 1" call before the "#include" statements - oops! Just wanted to post in case this helps someone else.